# Check certain URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I add something in JavaScript that will check the website URL of someone on a web site and then redirect to a certain page on the website, if a match is found? for example...

the string we want to check for, will be `mydirectory`, so if someone went to `mysite.com/mydirectory/anyfile.php` or even `mysite.com/mydirectory/index.php` JavaScript would then redirect their page / url to `mysite.com/index.php` because it has `mydirectory` in the URL, how can I do that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, then it is fairly simple and can be achieved using document.URL

```
var search = 'mydirectory'; // The string to search for in the URL.
var redirect = 'http://mysite.com/index.php' // Where we will direct users if it's found
if(document.URL.substr(search) !== -1) { // If the location of 
    // the current URL string is any other than -1 (doesn't exist)
    document.location = redirect // Redirect the user to the redirect URL.
}
```

Using document.URL you can check anything in the URL, however you might want to look into using something like Apache's mod_rewrite for redirecting the user before they even load the page.

Comment: You have an extra `=` in your if condition.

Comment: It's better style to use exactly equals (=== and !==) to avoid problems such as (0 == false) or (-1 == '-1') returning true. It doesn't affect this situation, but it doesn't hurt either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 0):

Check out `window.location`, particularly [it's properties and methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties). You would be interested in (part of the) `pathname` property (you can split it on `/`) and the `href` property to change the page.

This is all assuming the javascript is being served in the first place; so I'm assuming `anyfile.php` and `index.php` would all result in the JS being served and not some 'generic 404' message.